# Why is my hard disk making Windows 7 freeze?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, freeze

I have a 2TB HDD formatted with 2 partitions, 1TB each. One partition is for storage the other one is used for Windows 7 backup. The HDD is a Seagate Barracuda, originally it was an external USB hard drive but I put it inside the system for performance reasons.

The problem is that the systems freezes for few minutes when the computer is inactive for long time. I have disabled "Turn off disk after", "Sleep" or "Hibernate" from power options but still have the same problem.

The system works fine when I disconnect this drive.

I have 3 others hard disks on the system (older than this one) and the system is working just fine when this drive is removed.

Comment: Is this a "Green" drive?

Comment: Is it literally freezing for a few minutes, or just a few seconds? Because it is normal for it to hang for a second or so while the hard disk is spinning back up.

Comment: It is freezing for few minutes...